# Präteritum vs Plusquamperfekt

Tags: difference

Ich bin auf diesen Satz gestoßen und weiß nicht wirklich gerade, was der Unterschied da ist.

> „Ich liebte Kunst, oder besser gesagt, hatte Kunst geliebt.“!

[image]

Comment: Bitte keine Texte in Bildern.

Comment: Bitte denke daran, dass diese Seite auch von blinden und sehbehinderten Menschen besucht wird. Wenn sie sich diese Seite vorlesen lassen, hören sie an der Stelle des Bildes derzeit nur den Text »enter image description here«. Bitte editiere deine Frage und schreibe in die Bildbeschreibung den ganzen Text, der in dem Bild zu sehen ist. Oder noch besser: Lass das Bild ganz weg und schreibe nur den Text.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich liebte Kunst.

Der Autor spricht zur Zeit T über Zeit T-1. Zur Zeit T-1 liebte er Kunst.

> Ich hatte Kunst geliebt.

Der Autor spricht zur Zeit T über Zeit T-1, und zu dieser Zeit liebte er Kunst nicht mehr. Er liebte sie aber zur noch früheren Zeit T-2.

Comment: Der Autor spricht in der *Erzählzeit*, bzw. in der *Vergangenheit der Erzählzeit*. Diese Erzählzeit kann auch die Zukunft sein! Beispiel: *Im Jahr 2458 **sah sich** die Menschheit schon wieder einer selbstgemachten Katastrophe gegenüber. Man **hatte** alle Föns der Erde zufällig gleichzeitig eingeschaltet.*